# Bind and socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

Is it necessary to bind a socketfd to a IP addrees while writting a server socket programming.
I mean is it possble to write a socket programming without calling bind system call?
Like socket -> listen -> accept -> read/write/ -> close.

Comment: Call me on my cell, and I'll answer this question for you.

Answer (score 2):

socket should be bind to port or unix socket file.
Do you mean `you don't want to define port number for listen`? Then bind port number 0. It works with random port.

```
memset((char *) &reader_addr, 0, sizeof(reader_addr));
reader_addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
reader_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
reader_addr.sin_port = 0;

if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&reader_addr, sizeof(reader_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("reader: bind");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your suggestion. I tried with your suggested configuration, but while connecting from the client to server, I got Connect: Connection refused error. On client side I used the '0' to connect to the server. Also is there any way to identify that server in listening on which port in  netstat output. If I provide the port number I can do, but as you said it will choose randomly, How can I know from netstat command?

Comment: Nobody said you could use port zero at the client. If you use port zero at the server, you have to discover what port was allocated, via getsockname(), and use that port number at the client when connecting.

Answer (score 1):

You use `bind` at the server end.

Simply imagine it is a switch board for your office. The `bind` gives it a phone number so that other people know what number to phone. The the operator `listen` answers and puts the call through (i.e. process it).